Subsets and Sets Question in New Zealand MO

For any positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the number of subsets of ${1, 2, . . . , n}$ whose
sum is equal to $n$. Does there exist infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that $f(m) = f(m + 1)$?  (Note that each element in a subset must be distinct.)

This is a New Zealand MO question and in their solution, they state that, by Michael Albert, that if we make $S(n)$ the set that fulfills what the question asks for, then $S(n)→S(n+1)$ is considered as a 'map', then this map would be an injection (needs proof but easy) and not a surjection provided that $S(n + 1)$ contains a set whose largest and second largest elements differ by one.
They state that a proof is needed and I would appreciate it if anybody could explain this to me, with the proof, as this will help me to understand the question better.
FYI: I have added my solution below.
Thank you very much!

You neither define $S(n),$ nor tell us what the map is. $X\to Y$ doesn't define anything, it just means some map from$X$ to $Y.$ Any map.

Let S(n) is the set of such subsets that fufills what the question states.

Don't put it in comments, put it in the question. As written, your question is horribly incomplete.

Let $S(n)$ be the set of such subsets. Consider the $S(n)$ to $S(n + 1)$ that adds one
to the largest element of each $A ∈ S(n)$.
For even $n = 2k ⩾ 2$ this is true since we can take ${k, k + 1} ∈ S(n + 1)$ and for
odd $n = 2k + 1 ⩾ 5$ this is true since we can take ${1, k, k + 1}$. So for $n ⩾ 5$, we must have $f(n) < f(n + 1)$ and there do not exist infinitely many such pairs.

Something seems to be missing here. What is true?

If there exist infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that $f(m)=f(m+1)$.
